# String theory: why do c-zero modes have to raise from global solutions to c e.o.ms?

Tags: string-theory, string, string-field-theory

I'm studying string theory at an introductory level and really can't understand the concept of c-zero modes. In particular, the procedure to find them.
I read on the Tong lectures that they have to be the modes of expantion for the GLOBALLY defined solutions of the equations of motion (so that the action becomes zero). Why is it neccessary the 'globally defined' condition?
Hope my doubt is clear.